# Passing a value to a method, without declaring an extra variable

Tags: angular

I was trying to pass a variable value `$('#new_new_unit_input').value`, to my `onAddUnit(...)`-method, which accepts a string.

Here is what I tried:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="new_new_unit_input" required placeholder="Eine neue Einheit angeben" name="new_unit_input" type="text" class="form-control">
          <!--<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="new_unit_input.touched && !new_unit_input.valid">Bitte eine Zutat eingeben!</div>-->
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddUnit($('#new_new_unit_input').value)">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This fails, I get:

> _co.$ is not a function

And I was wondering maybe there is a better (angular) way, without declaring an extra variable ?

To validate `new_new_unit_input` would be nice as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input you need to declare the variable with #

```
<input #new_new_unit_input id="new_new_unit_input" required placeholder="Eine neue Einheit angeben" name="new_unit_input" type="text" class="form-control">
```

and in your `function you can pass it directly with onAddUnit(new_new_unit_input.value)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: ([stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-formarray-example-9fv4q4?file=src/app/app.component.html))

Add the `#new_new_unit_input` reference:

```
<input id="new_new_unit_input" #new_new_unit_input required placeholder="Eine neue Einheit angeben" name="new_unit_input" type="text" class="form-control">
```

Reference the call in the add

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddUnit(new_new_unit_input.value)">Add</button>
```

The full example is the following

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="new_new_unit_input" #new_new_unit_input required placeholder="Eine neue Einheit angeben" name="new_unit_input" type="text" class="form-control">
          <!--<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="new_unit_input.touched && !new_unit_input.valid">Bitte eine Zutat eingeben!</div>-->
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddUnit(new_new_unit_input.value)">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I reopen that `Modal`, I still got the old value. How to change that ?

Comment: You can't. Whenever you open the modal, a new component is initialized. You need to pass the value from the parent that opens it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are actually two Angular ways - both using `#` in HTML.

I just built a simple example for you:

**Option 1:** Pass the value from your HTML-file

HTML:

```
<input #myInput>
<button (click)="onButtonClick(myInput.value)">Click to log value!</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
onButtonClick(pValue: string): void {
  console.log(pValue);
}
```

**Option 2:** Use `@ViewChild`

HTML:

```
<input #myInput>
<button (click)="onButtonClick()">Click to log value!</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChild('myInput', {static: false}) input: ElementRef;

onButtonClick(): void {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
}
```